# how to get AutoIncrement value after JetUpdate() in Extensible Storage Engine (JetBlue)

Tags: c++, c, database, extensible-storage-engine

after calling JetSetColumns() and then JetUpdate() how do I retrieve the values for any freshly assigned autoincrement values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call JetUpdate() the third arg is a 'bookmark'.  Once JetUpdate() completes you can seek to the bookmark using

JetGotoBookmark() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683554(EXCHG.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is also possible to retrieve the autoincrement value **before** calling JetUpdate, because the value is assigned when JetUpdate is called. You need to use the JET_bitRetrieveCopy option with JetRetrieveColumn.

For an example in managed code see the "How Do I Retrieve an Auto-Increment Column Value?" section on this [page](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowDoI).